# Show that $\sin45°+\sin15°=\sin75°$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Steps I took:

1) Finding the value of the left hand side

$$\sin45=\sin\frac { 90 }{ 2 } =\sqrt { \frac { 1-\cos90 }{ 2 }  } =\sqrt { \frac { 1 }{ 2 }  } =\frac { \sqrt { 2 }  }{ 2 } $$

$$\sin15=\sin\frac { 30 }{ 2 } =\sqrt { \frac { 1-\cos30 }{ 2 }  } =\sqrt { \frac { 1-\frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 }  }{ 2 }  } =\frac { \sqrt { 2-\sqrt { 3 }  }  }{ 2 } $$

So, $\sin45+\sin15=\frac { \sqrt { 2 } +\sqrt { 2-\sqrt { 3 }  }  }{ 2 } $

2) Rewriting $\sin75$

$$\sin75=\sin(45+30)=\sin45\cos30+\sin30\cos45$$
$$=\frac { \sqrt { 2 }  }{ 2 } \cdot \frac { \sqrt { 3 }  }{ 2 } +\frac { 1 }{ 2 } \cdot \frac { \sqrt { 2 }  }{ 2 } $$
$$=\frac { \sqrt { 6 } +\sqrt { 2 }  }{ 4 } $$

So now I have these two expressions that are obviously equal (when I compute them) but how do I show them as being equal to each other. I assume the question is implying for the resulting expressions to look equal.

Comment: Hint: Denest the radical in ans 1.

Comment: In more detail, square answer 1 and then take its square root.

Comment: Since both expressions are positive, you can show that they are equal by squaring each of them and showing that the squares are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets easier if you compute $\sin 15^\circ$ in the same way that you computed $\sin 75^\circ$:

$$
\sin 15^\circ = \sin(45^\circ-30^\circ)=\sin 45^\circ \cos 30^\circ - \sin 30^\circ \cos 45^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4} \, .
$$

For an alternate approach, you could use a [sum-to-product formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) to note that

$$\sin 15^\circ+\sin 45^\circ = 2 \sin 30^\circ \cos 15^\circ $$
and proceed from there...

Comment: and then square your first answer?

Comment: No, then you don't need to square anything. Just compute $\sin 15^\circ+\sin 45^\circ$ using this expression for $\sin 15^\circ$ and all will (hopefully) become clear.

Comment: Your answer was $\frac { \sqrt { 6 } -\sqrt { 2 }  }{ 4 } $ and my answer was $\frac { \sqrt { 6 } +\sqrt { 2 }  }{ 4 } $

Comment: Yes, but my answer is just $\sin 15^\circ$ and yours is supposed to be $\sin 15^\circ+\sin 45^\circ$. $$\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}+\sin 45^\circ=\dots$$

Comment: So apply the same formula to get $sin45°$ and then add that answer to the one you got... and it should equal to the $sin75$

Comment: Pretty much. But you shouldn't need a formula to get $\sin 45^\circ$ (based on the algebra in your question, you already know what it is).

Answer (score 2):

Both of them are positive, so let's square both of them:
first one will give: 
\begin{gather}
\frac{1}{4} \left( 4  - \sqrt{3} + 2 \sqrt{4-2\sqrt{3}}\right) = \frac{1}{4} \left( 4 - \sqrt{3} + 2 \sqrt{1-2\sqrt{3}+3}\right) =\frac{1}{4} \left( 4 - \sqrt{3} + 2 \sqrt{(1-\sqrt{3})^2}\right) = \frac{1}{4} \left( 4 - \sqrt{3} + 2 (\sqrt{3}-1) \right) =  \frac{1}{4} \left( 2 + \sqrt{3}  \right) = 0.5 + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}
\end{gather}
the second one:
$$\frac{1}{16} \left( 6+2+2\sqrt{12}\right) = 0.5+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4} $$

Answer (score 2):

mathisfun did a nice job of showing you how to reconcile your answers.

Another way of showing that $\sin(45^\circ) + \sin(15^\circ) = \sin(75^\circ)$ is to use the formula

$$\sin\alpha + \sin\beta = 2\sin\left(\frac{\alpha + \beta}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\alpha - \beta}{2}\right)$$

with $\alpha = 45^\circ$ and $\beta = 15^\circ$.

\begin{align*}
\sin(45^\circ) + \sin(15^\circ) & = 2\sin\left(\frac{45^\circ + 15^\circ}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{45^\circ - 15^\circ}{2}\right)\\
& = 2\sin\left(\frac{60^\circ}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{30^\circ}{2}\right)\\
& = 2\sin(30^\circ)\cos(15^\circ)\\
& = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \cos(15^\circ)\\
& = \cos(15^\circ)\\
& = \sin(90^\circ - 15^\circ)\\
& = \sin(75^\circ)
\end{align*}

since $\cos\theta = \sin(90^\circ - \theta)$.

Comment: Is this referring to how they complement each other?

Comment: The cosine is the sine of the complementary angle.  You can see why the formula $\cos\theta = \sin(90^\circ - \theta)$ holds for acute angles if you draw a right triangle with acute angle $\theta$.  The other acute angle has measure $90^\circ - \theta$.  The side opposite the angle with measure $90^\circ - \theta$ is the side adjacent to the angle with measure $\theta$.

Comment: Salman Khan, from Khan Academy, makes note of that many times in his videos. I finally see an applicable use for it. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$\frac { \sqrt { 2 } +\sqrt { 2-\sqrt { 3 }  }  }{ 2 }$$

By squaring the numerator and denominator:

$$\frac {\left(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2-\sqrt{3}}\right)^2}{4} = \frac{2+2-\sqrt{3}+ 2\sqrt{4-2\sqrt3}}{4} = \frac{4-\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{4-2\sqrt3}}{4}$$

Next we must find:

$$\sqrt{4-2\sqrt3}$$

Let's call the answer $a-\sqrt{b}$

Now, we can say that:

$$\left(\sqrt{4-2\sqrt3}\right)^2 = 4 - 2\sqrt{3} = (a-\sqrt{b})^2 = a^2 - 2a\sqrt{b} + b$$

Therefore we can say:

$$a^2 + b = 4$$

and

$$2a\sqrt{b} = 2\sqrt{3}$$

We then get that: $a = 1$, $b = 3$

Therefore, $$\sqrt{4-2\sqrt3} = 1 - \sqrt{3}$$

Substituting:

$$\frac{4-\sqrt{3}+2\sqrt{4-2\sqrt3}}{4} = \frac{4-\sqrt{3}+2(1-\sqrt{3})}{4} = \frac{4-\sqrt{3}+2 - 2\sqrt{3}}{4} = \frac{6- 3\sqrt{3}}{4} = \frac{3(2- \sqrt{3})}{4}$$

Can you take the rest from here?

Comment: Since $1 - \sqrt{3} < 0$, $\sqrt{4 - 2\sqrt{3}} = \sqrt{3} - 1$.